# Icmp echo через tcp канал - возможно ли?

Tags: c#, ssh, ping

Добрый день.

Есть ли какая-либо возможность отправить ping запрос через tcp соединение?

Грубо говоря, есть поднятый ssh тунель (tcp соединение) до определенного хоста, нужно через него пингануть этот хост.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это возможно, если Ваш туннель поднят как описано в man по ssh в разделе
SSH-BASED VIRTUAL PRIVATE NETWORKS.

Answer (score 1):

ICMP это диагностический протокол отладки сети. Ip делятся на три протокола tcp, udp и icmp. Если у вас поднят тунель, то вы можете "пинговать" удаленную сторону, но это будет не tcp, а icmp